# JAXB support for SOAP style arrayType

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, jaxb

I'm trying to make a new version of a server that previously used Axis 1.4 to respond to SOAP RPC requests using Spring-WS. I have a few of the RPC calls working, but I'm stuck trying to satisfy a request that expects a SOAP body that looks like this:

```
<rpcCallResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <responseElement soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[5]" 
        xsi:type="soapenc:Array" 
        xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <responseElement xsi:type="xsd:string">val1</responseElement>
      <responseElement xsi:type="xsd:string">val2</responseElement>
      <responseElement xsi:type="xsd:string">val3</responseElement>
      <responseElement xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
      <responseElement xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
   </responseElement>
</rpcCallResponse>
```

I'm struggling to write the XML schema for this, and to get the JAXB marshaller to shove the `xsi:type` annotations into the response.

What's the correct XML schema to use/set of annotations to use to get this to marhsal (Java -> XML) correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I found that works for getting the arrayType added is to, instead of deriving from the http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/ schema, use a custom schema of the form:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:attribute name="arrayType" type="xs:QName" />
</xs:schema>
```

...which replaces the type of the `arrayType` attribute with an `xs:QName` (vs. the actual type, which is just an `xs:string`). The advantage of using a `QName` seems to be that JAXB will take the QName's namespace and shove it onto the element when serialization happens -- which was the main blocker on getting a working schema above.

The schema for above now looks something like:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:encoding="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    targetNamespace="http://foo.com/bar"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="soapenc.xsd" />

    <xs:element name="rpcCallResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="responseElement">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="responseElement" maxOccurs="5" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```